# Thousand separator in a JavaScript counter

Tags: javascript, counter, separator

I have this counter JavaScript snippet:

```
var START_DATE = new Date("October 24, 2015 11:00:00"); // start
var INTERVAL = 1; // sec
var START_VALUE = 0; // init value
var INCREMENT = 0.13; // value per sec
var count = 0;

window.onload = function()
{
 var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1000;
 var now = new Date();

 count = parseInt((now - START_DATE)/msInterval,10) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE;
 document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = count.toFixed(2);
 setInterval("count += INCREMENT; document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = count.toFixed(2);", msInterval);    
}
```

The counter may eventually display values in thousands and millions. My question is how to separate the thousands with a comma/blank space? I tried to achieve this via CSS, but apparently the options available here are not very practical. I was wondering on a possible solution in JavaScript. I found this on jsfiddle, but I am not sure how to apply it on the result of the counter?

```
function addCommas(n){
var rx=  /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
return String(n).replace(/^\d+/, function(w){
    while(rx.test(w)){
        w= w.replace(rx, '$1,$2');
    }
    return w;
});
}
```

Comment: So you don't know how to use a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript's built in toLocaleString function.  Here is an [example from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

```
var number = 3500;

console.log(number.toLocaleString()); // Displays "3,500" if in U.S. English locale
```

There are some additional options you can use with that function, but they are not all supported by various browsers.  Basic use should work though.